# SQL Server 2014 job error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am running a SQL Server Job and I'm getting the following error.

> The job failed. The job was invoked by the user sa. The last step to run was step 1. Executed as user. NT service\SQLAgent$SQL2014. Miscrosoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility version 12.0.50000.0 for 32-bit.

Can anyone tell me why this happening?

Comment: Can you paste the logs,which you can view in job history

Comment: TheGameiswar It's too big to paste. What are you looking for?

Comment: Sounds like it's failing on step 1.  Need more info beyond if you want an answer beyond that.

Comment: pasting logs may help,until unless one can;t provide a blanker answer,please paste the log,if big paste in paste bin and provide the link

Comment: @TheGameiswar where is the bin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @TheGameiswar I pasted it. Now how do you see it? My user name is jmolina

Comment: you can paste as guest,please read some links on how to paste as guest

Comment: @TheGameiswar I pasted it as a guest. The header is SQL Job Log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120159/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-john-molina).

Comment: Click on the link to get into chat,lets discuss there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your pastebin of the error, it looks like the oledb source connection in your package is setup to login as sa.  On a side note, this is bad practice...

This error usually indicates one of two things.  Either the server instance is setup to only allow windows auth or the password entered in the connection manager for user sa is not correct.